# jQuery not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to highlight select elements in a bootstap modal layer using the following jQUery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    pqGlobal.selectInputStyle();
}


selectInputStyle: function () {
    jQuery( "select" ).on( "focus blur", function() {
          var elem = jQuery( this );
          elem.toggleClass( "focusBorder", elem.is( ":focus" ) );
        });
},
```

I understand that the modal layer is getting loaded after the window load event.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    pqGlobal.selectInputStyle();
}); function selectInputStyle{
    jQuery( "select" ).on( "focus blur", function() {
          var elem = jQuery( this );
          elem.toggleClass( "focusBorder", elem.is( ":focus" ) );
        });
}`

Comment: This worked my friend. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
jQuery( "select" ).on( "focus blur", function() {
  var elem = jQuery( this );
  elem.toggleClass( "focusBorder", elem.is( ":focus" ) );
});
```

try this:

```
jQuery( document ).on( "focus blur", "select", function() {
  var elem = jQuery( this );
  elem.toggleClass( "focusBorder", elem.is( ":focus" ) );
});
```

Which uses [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), allowing dynamic content to inherit jquery events.

> Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation
>   (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the
>   element on which the event originated. **It allows us to attach a single
>   event listener for elements that exist now or in the future.**